# What will happen if a downvoted answer is accepted as the answer?

Tags: support, downvotes

Somebody downvoted my answer and the question owner accepted my answer. Will that affect the downvoted one's reputation score? As I don't have a downvote option, what is the explanation?

Comment: How can you downvote an answer with <125 reputation?

Comment: You will loose -1 rep regardless of what happens otherwise to the answer (unless it's removed). - If it's your answer then: `100 rep - 2 rep + 15 rep`. so, you'll end up with 113 rep in total

Comment: Did you answer the question? If so when the question owner accepts it your score will change, if not it won't.

Comment: No actually somebody downvoted my answer. and question owner accepted my answer

Comment: @Sree You'll get +15 for the accept and -2 for the downvote...

Comment: @JonClements : Will that affect the downvoted ones score ?

Comment: @Sree, no, only the initial downvote will give them -1 reputation, when used on answers. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: @Draken : Thanks . As I don't have downvote option . I got this doubt . Thanks for your time :)

Comment: To answer question in title - OP get to use bad code/suggestion provided in the answer (probably due to not following good practices like using string concatenation to build SQL query).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing will happen. The downvote and accept vote don't affect one another; their effects on the answer are combined. The -1 penalty imposed on you for downvoting the answer and the -2 on the one who posted the answer both remain effective. The +15 awarded for acceptance also remains effective.